# Embedding $\mathbb{G}_a$ into $GL_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices, algebraic-groups, hopf-algebras

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$.  I'd like to find interesting examples of closed embeddings $\mathbb{G}_a(k)\hookrightarrow GL_2(k)$, where $\mathbb{G}_a(k)$ is $(k,+)$.  For any non-zero $a\in k$, we have the two standard embeddings:

$$c\longmapsto\begin{pmatrix}1&ac\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\qquad\qquad c\longmapsto\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ac&1\end{pmatrix}$$
Also, for $p=2$ we have the embedding

$$c\longmapsto\begin{pmatrix}1+ac&ac\\ac&1+ac\end{pmatrix}$$

What are other examples of such embeddings, either in arbitrary positive characteristic, or in a specific positive characteristic?  If you prefer to think in terms of coordinate algebras, this problem is equivalent to finding surjective Hopf algebra maps from $k[GL_2]$ to $k[\mathbb{G}_a]$.  Thanks in advance.

Edit: Thanks to the comments, we have for any $a,b\in k$, not both $0$, an embedding given by

$$c\longmapsto\begin{pmatrix}1-abc&a^2c\\-b^2c&1+abc\end{pmatrix}$$

This example genralizes the previous $3$.  Do all embeddings have this form?

Comment: Trivially, any and all conjugates of the two you already have.

Comment: I guess $c\mapsto\pmatrix{1&c^p\cr0&1\cr}$ doesn't qualify, because it won't yield a surjective mapping of coordinate rings. It looks like a closed mapping at the level of sets, but fails at the level of structure sheafs (or group schemes that is equivalent to Hopf algebra POV). My guess is that you have found all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the image of a homomorphism $f:\mathbb{G}_a\to \mathrm{GL}_2$ is smooth, connected, and solvable. Thus, the image is contained in a Borel subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2$. But, the Borel subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_2$ are all conjugate to

$$B_2=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}\ast & \ast\\ 0 & \ast\end{pmatrix}\right\}\subseteq \mathrm{GL}_2$$

Thus, up to conjugation, we may assume that $f$ has image in $B_2$. But, let us note that

$$B_2= R_u(B_2)\rtimes T_2=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 & \ast\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\right\}\rtimes \left\{\begin{pmatrix}\ast & 0\\ 0 & \ast\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

and so, in particular, we see that $B_2/R_u(B_2)$ is a torus, and thus $f(\mathbb{G}_a)$ lands inside of $R_u(B_2)\cong \mathbb{G}_a$.

The endomorphism ring in characteristic $p$ is $k_\sigma[F]$--the non-commutative $k$-algebra generated by the Frobenius map (e.g. see  [Mil, Example 14.40]). Explicitly if one has $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n a_i F^i$ in $k_\sigma[F]$ this is the map

$$\mathbb{G}_a\to\mathbb{G}_a:x\mapsto \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^{p^i}$$

Thus, in summation, we see that up to $\mathrm{GL}_2(k)$-conjugacy the homomorphisms $\mathbb{G}_a\to \mathrm{GL}_2$ are all of the form

$$x\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}1 & \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^{i^p}\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

for some element $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n a_i F^i \in k_\sigma[F]$. Evidently these are embeddings if and only if $n=0$ and $a_0\in k^\times$.

[Mil] Milne, J.S., 2017. Algebraic groups: The theory of group schemes of finite type over a field (Vol. 170). Cambridge University Press.